# How to update records which also are updated by by batch process

Tags: batch, update, after-trigger, locking

We currently have a batchprocess running from a managed package which runs every day for almost the whole day to update records of an object. When a user tries to do an update on this object we have a trigger which does an after update on this object we get the error:

```
first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records:
```

As far as I have read this is caused by records being locked by the batch proces. One solution would be to add FOR UPDATE in the  soql but since this is a managed package this is no option.

What would the solution be? Since I suppose that only the current batch gets locked, can this be resolved by passing the update from the trigger to a future class or should this be resolved in a different way?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

I found a possible solution:

```
Approval.isLocked(recordId)
```

This method also accepts List, SObject, or List.

What I do not understand is how to use this.
The return value is a map with Ids and Boolean values if locked or not.

I.e.

```
Approval.isLocked(listToUpdate);
```

Do I loop trough the map until the list is unlocked and then?:

```
update listToUpdate;
```

UPDATE

- The record where this fails has 5 childrecords
- I tried with future but this throws an error since the batch is also future

Comment: if the package allows the scope size to be reduced from 200 to a smaller value, you might have less frequent locks; deferring to an async means you need to build a retry mechanism

Comment: I suspect that this problem indicates you _also_ have significant data skew. Is there an exceptionally large volume of child records associated with one or a very small number of parents?

Comment: @DavidReed The record which threw this error has 5 child records. Can this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the batchprocess running from the managed package was causing our trigger to fail. I ended up removing the updates from the trigger and adding to a batch proces running every half an hour which seemed to resolve the issue.